# Add hours to date to achieve next 6:00

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have TIMESTAMP and I want to modify this timestamp to create new timestamp with next 6am.
Eg

```
2020-09-01 22:00:00 -> 2020-09-02 06:00:00
2020-08-30 04:00:00 -> 2020-08-30 06:00:00
```

any idea if it's doable in one step?

for now I have pseudocode such as:

```
hour = extract(hour from mytimestamp)
if hour > 0 and hour < 7 then
  date_trunc('hour', mytimestamp) + interval 6-hour
else
  date_trunc('day', mytimestamp) + interval '1 day' + interval '6 hours'
end if;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CASE expression to do that:

```
select case 
         when the_column::time > time '07:00' then (the_column::date + 1) + time '06:00'
         else the_column::date + time '06:00'
       end as new_column
from the_table
```

`the_column::date` converts the timestamp to a date (without a time). The desired time is then simply added to that date to get the new timestamp. To get the next day, `+1` is used.